# C++ winAPI basics - switching through windows

Tags: c++, winapi

Not very sure how to explain it in a clear way. Basicaly, the thing is that I'm looking for a method to change a *current active window* ( Self-produced def., hope it'll be understandable enough ) - window, where the text is directly typed right now. Whooh.

What have I allready discovered is [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) help and SetFocus() or SetActiveWindow(), but it doesn't solve my problem ( or, what is also possible, I'm just using it in a wrong way ).

Simply:

```
HWND Dest = GetFocus();
... //Some moving around on the 'alt-tab level' :-|
SetFocus(Dest);
```

Doesn't set the Dest window active again.
Please, excuse for the newbie questions, hope it won't take much time from you. Thanx!

Comment: Have you tried to use `SetForegroundWindow` function?

Comment: You can call `SetForegroundWindow` but it won't work. The user gets to decide what's in the foreground. Your program does not.

Comment: Bringing the window to the top is not so nescessary, the other question is that it neither lets typing there. The context of it's using is quite primitive, as I've allready written so I just don't know how it could fail. After using SetFocus() / SetActiveWindow the keystrokes are still being applied to the previous window.

Comment: Thx so much to all of you. At last managed to do the trick, a little bit hacky, but nevertheless. GetForegroundWindow() and SetForegroundWindow() at last worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SetFocus() does not bring a window to the top. It just sets the keyboard focus.

[SetActiveWindow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646311%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on the other hand brings the specific window on top, but only if the application that calls it is also the application that owns it. ( according to the documentation).

When you say you did try SetActiveWindow() what do you mean? How did it fail? What results did it produce?

Another function you can try is [SetForegroundWindow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in case you want to activate a window belonging to another application but this has its problems as you see from below (directly from the documentation):

> The system restricts which processes can set the foreground window. A
>   process can set the foreground window only if one of the following
>   conditions is true:
>
> - The process is the foreground process.
> - The process was started by the   foreground process.
> - The process received the last input event.
> - There is no foreground process.
> - The foreground process is being debugged.
> - The foreground is not locked (see LockSetForegroundWindow).
> - The foreground lock time-out has expired (see       SPI_GETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT in SystemParametersInfo).
> - No menus are active.

Comment: It seems I'm mistaken at the level of understanding of simply storing the current working window in HWND obj. The GetFocus() terminates normally but for the fact that the value stored in Dest equalls to NULL. Then it's quite obvious that SetFocus() fails. Can you please enlighten me on this point - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If GetFocus() returns NULL then as the documentation says: "If the calling thread's message queue does not have an associated window with the keyboard focus, the return value is NULL." 
Which means you are calling GetFocus() when your application does not have the keyboard focus.
As David Heffernan says in the comments in the original post you can't force the user to have a certain app on Top.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [SetForegroundWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

Do however note that there are limitations on this, which are explained on the MSDN page remarks sections and I've copied here.

> The system restricts which processes can set the foreground window. A
> process can set the foreground window only if one of the following
> conditions is true:
>
> - The process is the foreground process.   The process was started by    the foreground process.
> - The process received the last input event.
> - There is no foreground process.
> - The foreground process is being debugged.
> - The foreground is not locked (see LockSetForegroundWindow).
> - The foreground lock time-out has expired (see    SPI_GETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT in SystemParametersInfo).
> - No menus are active.
>
> An application cannot force a window to the foreground while the user
> is working with another window. Instead, Windows flashes the taskbar
> button of the window to notify the user.

What that means is that if you don't own the current foreground process (which is probably the case when the user tabs around) then you can't set a new foreground window.

There are several hacks around (google SetForegroundWindow and you will find them) but they are hacks and not a good idea - **let the user decide what is in the foreground!** (also as Raymond Chen explains on his blog [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080801-00/) the hacks can often cause a program to hang)